# Loss and mAP chart in YOLOv4

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I'm still new to "You Only Look Once" object detection algorithm (YOLOv4 to be exact). I have some questions regarding the mAP and loss chart.

I tried to follow the instructions from [AlexeyAB Darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects), and train my custom object detector using Google Colabs. After the training, it shows the loss and mAP chart as shown below.

Loss and mAP chart:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is there any chart other than this?
2. Is this loss for training or validation?
3. Why is there a sudden drop near iteration 1200?
4. Is the output of the training only that chart and the weight files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes. But if you want to export the log and make a chart out of it, you can try this command:

`./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights -map | tee results.log`

2. The **blue curve** is the training loss or the error on the training dataset (specifically Complete Intersection-Over-Union or CIoU loss for YOLOv4). For more details on CIoU loss, [check this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.08287). The **red line** is the mean average precision at 50% Intersection-over-Union threshold (mAP@0.5), which checks if your model it is generalizing well on a *never-before-seen dataset* or *validation set.* If you want to understand mAP more, you can refer to this [easy-to-understand blogpost.](https://jonathan-hui.medium.com/map-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173)
3. Are you using a custom dataset? The drop near iteration 1200 might be caused by some problems in your dataset. To check, try these:

   (a) Check your dataset - run training with flag `-show_imgs` i.e. `./darknet detector train ... -show_imgs` and look at the `aug_...jpg` images, do you see correct truth bounded boxes?

   (b) Check generated files `bad.list` and `bad_label.list` if they exist. These files contain the label files that may have problems.
4. Yes. But if you enable the log file (check my answer - no. 1), then, no.

Comment: There is a green line tied with max_batches? What it means? Also in my case Map, the red line, does not apperes while training running. Is it appear after the training finished or I need to write a code for that?

Answer (score 1):

2. The loss in the chart is for validation
3. the drop near iteration 1200 is most probably because the mean precision is lower for that particular mini-batch of your data as compared to other mini-batches.
4. You might have to manually save the weights explicitly after the training is stopped.

For second and third question, please check point 2.2 at [When should I stop training | AlexeyAB
/
darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#when-should-i-stop-training)